# I need to Add Scroll Property To a Label Control Within A Panel Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, scroll, label

I have a Winform and there are few controls in It, At Top there is a panel and inside it there is a label control with Dock Property Fill, I have to populate dynamic text into that label control, Sometimes text is so bigger that it cannot been seen,

How to add Scroll or size increase of Panel and then Form in this scenario?

[image] 
I have enabled , AutoEllipses and also Enables the AutoScroll Property of Panel.

Comment: What about a multiline `TextBox` with `ReadOnly = true;` ?

Comment: I did with TextBox, but when we move mouse mouse over , it changes its cursor and also user can select the text, which I don't want ,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the Label in a Panel that is `AutoScroll`, then set width of `MaximumSize` of Label, then set the label to be `AutoSize`.

You should set width of `MaximumSize` enough less than panel to only vertical scroll bar be visible.

[image]

Comment: By Setting , AutoSize it grows more then Panel and No Docking works then

Comment: @DareDevil Yes, I made a mistake about dock. Follow the maximum size way.

Comment: @DareDevil I edited the answer, In dock way, my mistake was using enter in text, but `MaximumSize` works properly.

Comment: @DareDevil Let me know If you find the answer helpful:)